# including the parenthesis when using sed

Tags: bash, sed

In BASH, when we use sed command. if I have to replace a word say "sin" with "sin (x)"  what should I do? Its taking the parenthesis as something else and i am getting error

example:

```
sed -i "3s/.*/xaxis label \" "Time (fs)" /" sigma.bfile
```

(I could escape quotation marks, but not the ( or ) )

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us a sample of the input data you're working with and the exact sed command you used on it, the results you got and the results you were looking for. Also, note that `sed` is a separate utility altogether, and not actually part of the `bash` shell. If your question is only about how to formulate a command in sed, then there's no need for the `bash` tag on your question.

Comment: #Obligatory descriptive comment
title "HeI"
xaxis label "Time" 
yaxis label "sigma_11"
autoscale

is the sigma.bfile in which I have to edit the 3rd line - from "Time" to "Time (fs)" using sed command.

Thanks -- I am new to this -- yeaa I will remove the tag of bash.

Comment: Is that supposed to be sample input? How about [adding it to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46889450/edit)? Comments are a terrible place for formatted text. :)

Comment: any way its sorted. I am thankful for your time. Yes, from next time, I will put such thing sin the question. Cheers!

Comment: Don't edit "Solved" or any such marker in your question or its title. If one of the answers solved your issue, mark it as accepted.

Comment: @TejaswiNisanth, if "it's sorted" means that you have a solution to your problem, then that's great! As a poster of a question, though, your job is not over. If your solution was (or was part of) an answer below, then click the checkmark to the left of the question to mark this question as closed. It STILL would not hurt to improve this question, so that people coming to it in the future from a search engine have a clearer idea of what the problem was, so they can learn more from the solution that was provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using syntax highlighting can help you:

```
sed -i "3s/.*/xaxis label \" "Time (fs)" /"
       1                   2 3         4  5
```

The double quote 3 ends double quote 1, so the string `Time (fs)` appears unquoted. Double quotes don't nest. Parentheses have special meaning in the shell. Are you sure you wanted to end the quoted string by the double quote nubmer 3?

You probably wanted just

```
sed -i "3s/.*/xaxis label \"Time (fs)\"/"
```

which could be even simpler if you replaced double quotes by single quotes

```
sed -i '3s/.*/xaxis label "Time (fs)"/'
```

Comment: Ok, I changed it to  sed -i "3s/.*/xaxis label \""Time\"" /" sigma.bfile , I am having no problem. But the moment I use ( or ) its showing error

Comment: Awesome! the last line worked. Thanks a lot or explaining and taking time.